# сравнение минут и часов с диапазоном времени

Tags: c, r, if, время, сравнение

Пользователь вводит часы и минуты и в зависимости от введенных данных программа выводит "доброе утро" "добрый вечер" или "доброй ночи", в моем коде я сделал сравнение учитывая только часы , подскажите пожалуйста как сделать сравнение и по часам и по минутам , учитывая и часы и минуты ?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include "task2.h"

int main()
{
    int hour, min,sec;
    printf("Enter the time:");
    scanf("%d:%d:%d", &hour, &min,&sec);

    printf("%s", greet(hour, min));

    return 0;
 }
```

Файл с функцией

```
char* greet(int hour, int min)
{
    //hour = (hour + min) / 60;
    //min = (hour + min) % 60;

    if (0 < hour < 6)
        return "Good night";

    else if (6 < hour < 11)
        return "Good morning";
    else if (11 < hour < 18)
        return ("Good day");
    else if (18 < hour < 24)
        return "Good evening";
}

файл заголовка
char* greet(int hour, int min);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проще всего - переводите время в минуты и действуйте, как и ранее...
Просто иначе у вас получится слишком разветвленная логика.

```
char* greet(int hour, int min)
{
    const int morning = 6*60+30;   //6:30
    const int day     = 10*60+45;  //10:45
    const int evening = 18*60+30;  //18:30

    hour = hour*60+min;

    if (0 < hour && hour <= morning )
        return "Good night";

    if (hour <= day)
        return "Good morning";

    ...
```

И еще - вот такое сравнение

```
if (0 < hour < 6)
```

всегда истинно, потому что ложным или истинным будет сравнение `hour` с 0 - его результат всегда будет меньше 6 :)